# How would I restart or call a function inside a funciton Lua

Tags: function, lua

I want to know how to restart or call a function inside a function using Lua.

so I could do this

```
function a()
print("Function Starts")
a()
end
a()
```

So this would start function a, print to output, and then restart function a.

Comment: That's an infinite recursion. What you want is more likely a loop (for, while). Can you provide an actual purpose?

Comment: @wb Derp. I didn't think of that one. I am just trying to make a command console using computercraft in minecraft.

Comment: I dont get what you intend to do at the end. maybe a variable to stop would help you: local stop; function a() print('bla') if not stop then a() end; a()

Comment: I dont understand the question? What do you think is wrong with your code? What results were you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

For a command console you would normally loop indefinitely until the user enters some special keyword (like "quit") or ctrl-break. For example,

```
local moreCommands = true
while moreCommands do 
    command = io.read() -- get user input
    if command == 'quit' then 
         moreCommands = false
    else
         assert(loadstring(command))()
    end
end
```